# Sopcast on Ubunutu no sound and vlc problem

Tags: sound, sopcast

I installed sopcast on ubunutu. All works well, except two problems.

The first is that after starting a sopcast stream, all works well until after a time the sound is gone.

The second is that is I'm setting  vlc as External media player in preferences there is simply grey screen.

Thanks for those who try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't found a great solution but the following method works:

> netstat -a | egrep 'LISTEN'

Then go over all the ports that with LISTEN and see which are Sopcat via http://localhost:PORT_NUMBER/tv.asf

Open network stream with that url in vlc and you're good

Answer (score -1):

Just edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to disable `module-suspend-on-idle`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**  Could you expand your answer a bit so a reputation 1 user can actually follow the steps you described?